# How to prove Gödel's Completeness Theorem apply for uncountable language?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I follow up the prove from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tP0gWTnmb0c&list=PLjJhPCaCziSRSUtQiTA_yx5TJ76G_EqUJ&t=529), to prove the completeness theorem, one of the step is to build from a consistent set $\Gamma$ to a set $\Gamma^*$ that satisfy:

1. $\Gamma\subset\Gamma^*$
2. $\Gamma^*$ is maximum consistent
3. For every formula has the form $(\exists x_i\phi)\in\Gamma^* $ there is a constent witness, which means there exists a constent symbol $c$ so that $\phi(x_i;c)\in\Gamma^*$

The prove of this based on a lemma that:

For any consistent set $\Gamma$, and any $(\exists x_i\phi)\in\Gamma$, if there is a constent symbol $c$ that does not appear in any of the $\phi\in\Gamma$ then $\Gamma\cup\{\phi(x_i;c)\}$ is consistent

Thus we can line up all countable formulas $\phi_1,\phi_2,...$ so that constent symbol $c_i$ does not appear in $\Gamma$ and any of the $\phi_j, j<i$ and add them one by one in to the original $\Gamma$

However, if there is uncountable number of formulas, how to prove it?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly which method is being used here, but I would guess that  the argument doesn't depend on the enumeration for formulas being countable (of order type $\omega$), but will apply to uncountable well-orderings as well.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I haven't learn set theory, the only thing I know about is any set can be well ordered and any subset of well ordered set has a minimum element. So if you would be so kind to tell me more detail of how to prove?? Thanks a lot

Comment: Took a look at the video. It wasn't the juncture of the argument I originally had in mind. The lecturer is pretty vague about this section, and it's not clear to me that the argument he's sketching actually works, even for countable languages. Also, the usual (in my experience) way of Henkinizing the language doesn't use enumeration of the formulas (and doesn't need the axiom of choice in the countable case). I'll try to write an answer.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's being described here is the process of Henkinizing the theory $\Gamma$ where we extend to a larger theory $\Gamma'\supseteq \Gamma$ in a larger language $L'\supseteq L$ such that $\Gamma'$ remains consistent (provided $\Gamma$ is consistent) and satisfies the witness property: that if $\Gamma'\vdash \exists x \varphi$, then there is a constant symbol $c\in L'$ such that $\Gamma' \vdash \varphi(x/c).$

As I mentioned in the comments, there is a way to do this doesn't rely on an enumeration of formulas and doesn't require the axiom of choice regardless of the size of the language. (It is the next step where we extend a consistent theory to a maximal consistent theory that requires choice in general.)

We build the Henkinization as a countable sequence of extensions $L' = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty L_n$ and $\Gamma' = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \Gamma_n$ where $L_n\subseteq L_{n+1}$ and $\Gamma_n\subseteq \Gamma_{n+1}.$

Start with $L_0 = L$ and $\Gamma_0 = \Gamma$ and proceed by recursion. Let $L_{n+1} = L_n \cup \{c^n_\varphi: \varphi\in \operatorname{form}(L_n)\},$ i.e. each $c^n_\varphi$ is a brand new constant for each $L_n$-formula $\varphi.$ Then we let $\Gamma_{n+1} = \Gamma_n\cup \{\exists x \varphi \to \varphi( x/c_{\varphi}^n): \varphi\in \operatorname{form}(L_{n+1})\}.$

Then we can show that if $\Gamma_n$ is consistent, then $\Gamma_{n+1}$ must also be, and so by induction each $\Gamma_n$ is consistent. It follows that $\Gamma'$ is consistent, since any inconsistency would need to come from a finite number of formulas, and thus from formulas all contained in one of the $\Gamma_n$'s.

It is easy to see that $\Gamma'$ has the witness property, again using the fact that proofs only use a finite number of axioms: If $\Gamma' \vdash \exists x \varphi$ then for some $n$, $\Gamma_n\vdash\exists x \varphi.$ Then, $(\exists x \varphi \to \varphi(x/c_\varphi^n)\in \Gamma_{n+1},$ so $\Gamma_{n+1}\vdash \varphi(x/c_\varphi^n).$

To show that $\Gamma_n$ being consistent implies $\Gamma_{n+1}$ is consistent, assume to the contrary that a $\Gamma_{n+1}$ is inconsistent. This inconsistency must be generated from $\Gamma_n$ and finitely many of the new sentences in $\Gamma_{n+1}$.

There will be fewer symbols flying around if we assume there is just a single sentence of the form $\exists x \varphi \to \varphi(x/c)$ that generates the inconsistency. If this is the case, then $\Gamma_n\vdash  \exists x\varphi \land \lnot\varphi(x/c).$ But since $c$ doesn't occur in $\Gamma_n$, universal generalization gives $\Gamma_n \vdash \forall y (\exists x \varphi \land \lnot \varphi(x/y))$, where $y$ doesn't occur in $\varphi$, which is contradictory. So $\Gamma_n$ is inconsistent. This can be straightforwardly extended to the case with finitely many new sentences from $\Gamma_{n+1}.$